# How does unitarity relate $\langle \psi^\dagger \psi^\dagger\rangle$ and $\langle \psi^\dagger \psi\rangle$ in superconductors?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity

Let $\psi^\dagger(x)$ be the creation operator for electrons. I read an argument that a nonvanishing Cooper pair amplitude $\langle \psi^\dagger(x) \psi^\dagger(x)\rangle$ implies a diminished local single-particle density of states $\langle \psi^\dagger(x) \psi(x)\rangle$ because of unitarity. This seems intuitively correct but what is the precise statement and derivation?

Source: page 3 of [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.64.014512) makes this claim ( [Arxiv version here](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0010413) ).

Comment: Could you point some sources to where you've read this?

Comment: @LucasBaldo added